# Bokeh and Holoviews import error - inconsistent packages

Tags: python, anaconda, bokeh, holoviews

I had a Bokeh and Holoviews import error and followed a few re-install bokeh instructions in the forum which then caused this issue:

"WARNING:param.Dimension: Use method 'get_param_values' via param namespace"

```
Solving environment: \
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/win-64::anaconda==5.2.0=py36_3
  - defaults/win-64::holoviews==1.10.7=py36_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::hvplot==0.3.0=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::ipywidgets==7.2.1=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyterlab==0.32.1=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyterlab_launcher==0.10.5=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::widgetsnbextension==3.2.1=py36_0
  - defaults/win-64::_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf==0.1.0=py36he6757f0_0
```

Requirements:

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.3
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
Werkzeug==1.0.1

-------
pip install bokeh 
pip install holoviews
pip install hvplot
```

Comment: Show your requirements.txt and commands run

Comment: aniso8601==8.0.0
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.3
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
Werkzeug==1.0.1

Comment: then pip install bokeh, pip install holoviews

Comment: please update your question. also why not include bokeh and holoviews as part of the file?

Comment: I did them in different days, first I was installing Flask, the next day I added Bokeh.. okey editing the question now

Comment: this was all working well until hvplot come into play

Comment: The `anaconda` metapackage is likely the trouble here; it pins versions of dozens or hundreds of packages. Now that the distribution is installed, that metapackage is just going to hold you back, so I'd try removing it (`conda remove anaconda`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the Anaconda and re-installed it. Problem solved.